# 20dB/decade vs 6dB per octave - Loop Stability

Tags: voltage, dc-dc-converter, buck, control-system, boost

I am reading about the control loop stability of the DC-DC Converters.

And I read this criteria that the slope of the gain curve at 0dB (unity gain) should be 20dB/decade. But they don't tell why.

Question 1:
Can someone tell me why the slope should be that 20dB/decade and not any other value for the loop stability criteria?

And in some places they also use 6dB/octave. Like, why only these numbers : 20dB/decade or 6dB/octave? or in cases, multiples like 40dB/decade?

Question 2:
Can someone explain on why the slope is defined as 20dB/decade and 6dB/octave and not any other value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requirement is is part of the (simplified) Nyquist criterion for stability. It is derived from the fact that the slope of the magnitude function is related to a corresponding phase shift (Bode relation). This rule applies for all transfer functions which have "minimal-phase" properties (no delay within the feedback circuit, no zeros in the right half of the s-plane).

This criterion says that a magnitude slope of -20dB/dec causes a phase shift of -90deg and a slope of -40dB/dec is related to a phase shift of -180deg.

Because a negative feedback loop contains already a phase inversion (-180deg) an additional phase shift of -180deg (equivalent to -40dB/dec) could bring the circuit to the stability limit (loop gain with 360deg phase shift).

For this reason, we require that at such a frequency (with 360deg=0deg phase shift) the loop gain must be below unity (0 dB). Alternatively, we require that at the 0dB-crossing the phase must not yet have reached the critical value of 360deg.

That means: When the magnitude slope at the zero-crossing would be, for example, -35dB/dec. the closed-loop would be stable - however, with a rather small safety margin (phase margin).

For a slope of -20dB/dec, we have a sufficient margin of app. 60 deg. For this reason, a good amplifier with feedback should have a loop gain with a magnitude that crosses the 0dB-line with a slope of app (-30----20) dB/dec

**Comment**: Sometimes people are confused because in some publications the loop gain phase contains the phase inversion (-180deg) at the summing junction and in some other publications the loop gain does NOT contain this negative sign. That is the reason for the two different formulations of the stability limit: Loop gain phase of -180deg or -360deg.

For my opinion, the negative sign should always be included because it is a part of the loop. More than that, there are feedback loops where the negative sign (for negative feedback) is NOT located at the summing junction but at any other place within the loop. Therefore, I suggest that the loop gain definition should always contain the minus sign - and the stability limit is based on the 360deg criterion.

Finally, tt should be mentioned, in this context, that loop gain simulations, of course, contain the complete loop (including the neg. sign).

Answer (score 1):

Any first order low pass filter, above the cut-off frequency attenuates the output (with respect to the input) at 20 dB/decade. In real numbers this means that if you increase the frequency 10 times, the output voltage reduces by ten times. If you do the log stuff to convert to decibels then that's 20 dB/decade.

It's a simple math exercise to see that output amplitude falls by \$x\$ when the input signal frequency rises by \$x\$.

And, of course, if the frequency doubles (increases by an octave), then the amplitude halves. Do the log stuff again and that works out at 20 log (0.5) = -6.02 dB (approximately). In other words, it's the same thing i.e. 20 dB/decade = (approximately) 6 dB/octave.

A first order filter/system cannot change the phase angle by anything more than 90° across the whole spectrum so, if one end of the spectrum is perfectly stable, then so should the other end but, it might be 90° closer to the point of instability (a phase shift of 180°).

Comment: For 20dB/decade, if we increase the frequency by 10times, the output voltage would reduce by 100times, right?

Comment: No, a first order system behaves as I said. The power would reduce by 100 times but the voltage (or the current) would reduce by ten times @Newbie

Comment: I am actually think the voltage values would be double of the power values when converted in dB? Can you please clarify this. And could you tell me why you added the phrase (a phase shift of 180deg) at the end? What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @Newbie I think you need to re-examine your knowledge of decibels. If the voltage increases or decreases by (say) 1 dB then so does the power. I mention 180 degrees because, in a control system that uses negative feedback, if the phase difference between input and output (prior to negative feedback) becomes 180 degrees then, when negative feedback is applied, your control system will become an oscillator.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The answers regarding the need to crossover with a 20-dB/decade or a -1-slope are very good and explain that what matters is to reduce the phase lag stress when approaching crossover. However, I can see there are often questions regarding the stability limit: is it -180°, -360° or 0°?

What matters is the way the loop gain is measured and what it does include. If you look at the below picture excerpted from my [APEC 2010](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202010.pdf) seminar, you see that if the loop gain is measured while excluding the inversion brought by the op-amp (which is a 180° lag), then the limit for the stability analysis is -180° because if you add the inversion lag to it, you return the stimulus information in phase and sustained oscillations are ensured at crossover where the loop gain is 1:

[image]

If you now decide to include the inverting stage (the compensator), then the total phase lag to consider is -360° or 0° which is similar:

[image]

And this is what you will have when using a frequency response analyzer or FRA in the lab or with a simulation using SPICE or SIMPLIS for instance: you will read the phase margin from the 0° baseline. This is because you cut the loop and insert the ac perturbation in series while keeping the operating point intact.

Finally, as the below graph shows, the phase margin whether you include or not the inverting sign remains the same in all cases:

[image]

Hope this helps clarify this concept for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

First of all -20dB/decade and -6dB/octave represent exactly the same slope. They are effectively the same thing.

For the system to be stable when the loop is closed, the open loop phase lag should be significantly less than -180 degrees when the loop gain is 1 (unity).

An open loop gain slope of -20dB/decade exists simultaneously with an open loop phase lag of -90 degrees. A lag of -90 degrees at unity loop gain is significantly less than -180 degrees and so represents a very stable system.

An open loop gain slope of -40dB/decade exists simultaneously with an open loop phase lag of  -180 degrees. A lag of -180 degrees at unity loop gain represents an unstable system.

And so for the system to be stable the slope at unity loop gain can be equal to or greater than -20dB/decade but it shouldn't get too close to -40dB/decade or the loop phase lag will approach -180 degrees and the system will oscillate.

The difference between loop phase and -180 degrees at unity loop gain is referred to as the phase margin and its value is directly related to the slope of the loop gain response.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just a clarification. Why should the open loop phase lag be less than -180 and not 360? Because according to the barkhausen criteria, to avoid positive feedback we need to make sure the phase lag is not 360 right? But why is it -180?

Comment: @Newbie It is sometimes talked about as -180 and sometimes as -360.  When the whole loop is take into account there is an extra inversion which adds -180 degrees lag and so to be totally accurate one would say 360 degrees or 0 degrees lag rather than 180 degrees lag.

Comment: Newbie, see the comment in my detailed answer.

Comment: ....just to add to my comment. It makes no difference to a phase margin measurement whether you include the inversion or not. If you include the inversion then the loop gain is multiplied by -1 and so the magnitude of the loop gain remains unaffected. A loop phase lag of 90 degrees without the inversion included gives a phase margin of 180-90 = 90 degrees and with the inversion included gives the same phase margin of 360-270 = 90 degrees. It is just a more thorough and rigorous approach to take the whole loop into account and include the inversion.